# Netlogo: simulation of cellular differentiation pattern?

Tags: netlogo, bioinformatics, modeling

I am trying to simulate the differentiation pattern of a simple organism. This is how I'd like my breeds and variables to work:

Breeds: vegetatives and heterocysts. Vegetatives can divide, heterocysts can't. Vegetatives can become heterocysts. Ideally, once a heterocyst is formed, the closer a vegetative is to it, the less likely it is for it to become a heterocyst in turn.

Variables:

age: + 1 per tick, - 1 for newly-hatched turtles

bump: A means by which to displace all the turtles located 'ahead' of a newly-hatched turtle, so they don't overlap. I imagined the system a bit like a Newton's Cradle (http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/newtons-cradle-1.jpg)

pro: promoter. Accumulates partially randomly. Once it reaches a certain value ('concentration'), a vegetative would change breed to become a heterocyst. Value decreased by inh.

proL: label for pro, with rounded values.

inh: inhibitor. Ideally this value should form a 'gradient' (highest in turtles near heterocysts, lowest further away).

The obvious problem that I can see is that I get a lot of contiguous heterocysts. Which is sort of what I've been trying to avoid. But I can't see what went wrong...Please help?

```
to setup
  clear-all
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
  ask turtles [ set size 1 ]
end

to setup-turtles
  create-vegetatives 1
  ask turtles [
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  set shape "circle"
  set color 65]
end

to go
  divide
  add-age
  move
  differentiate
  tick
end

turtles-own [age
  bump
  inh
  pro
  proL]


breed [vegetatives vegetative]
breed [heterocysts heterocyst]

to add-age
  ask turtles [
    set age age + 1
    ifelse show-age?
    [ set label age ]
    [ set label "" ]
  ]
end


to divide
ask vegetatives [
if random 100 < 2 [
hatch 1[
set bump 1
set age age - 1
set inh 0
]
]]
end

;;Trying to get only one turtle per patch, making the others move
to move
ask turtles[
while [bump = 1] [
  ifelse not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 180 1[
    rt 180
    fd 1
    set bump 0
    if any? other turtles-here[
        ask other turtles-here
      [set bump 1]
    ]
  ]
  [fd 1
  set bump 0
  if any? other turtles-here[
    ask other turtles-here[
      set bump 1]
    ]
]
]]
end


to differentiate
  ask turtles[
    set pro (pro - inh + (random 2))
    set proL round pro
    ifelse show-proL?
    [ set label proL ]
    [ set label "" ]
    create-links-with other turtles-on patch-ahead 1
    create-links-with other turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 180 1
    if breed = vegetatives [
      if any? link-neighbors[
      ifelse any? link-neighbors with [breed = heterocysts]
        []
        [set inh mean [inh] of link-neighbors]
        ]
    if any? vegetatives with [pro > 50] 
       [ask vegetatives with [pro > 50]
          [set breed heterocysts
           set color brown
           set shape "circle"
           if any? link-neighbors[
             ask link-neighbors with [breed != heterocysts]
               [set inh 2]]
    ]]
  ]]
clear-links
end
```